# MissingMethod exception in domain class

Tags: grails

Everytime I restart my application, I have a MissingMethodException on dynamic methods of Grails domain class.

I have 3 classes :

Manager.groovy : That class contains a Java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and an init method that creates Worker and submits those Workers to the executor.

Worker.groovy : implements Runnable and call Domain dynamic methods. Ex: MyDomain.get()

Bootstrap.groovy: in the init method I call the manager.init()

Sometimes the worker call dynamics method on domain and I got MissingMethodException.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your `Worker` class `extend` `Thread` (alternatively, let a `new Thread(Runnable)` decorate it) and pass the Groovy `ContextClassLoader` to it:

```
Worker worker = new Worker() // extends Thread
worker.setContextClassLoader(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
manager.schedule(worker, ..)
```

or

```
Thread worker = new Thread(new Worker())
worker.setContextClassLoader(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
manager.schedule(worker, ..)
```

Reason: The Groovy classloader has loaded special Groovy classes related to runtime metaprogramming, like associating meta classes and invoking virtual methods. Your `ThreadPoolExecutor` might use another, fresh, classloader that isn't aware of the Groovy "magic".

Comment: The answer explains everything. Thanks!!